# get last id form group by with some specific condition

Tags: postgresql

[database table record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyLFz.png)

I want the last record based on role and status
For example, i want to create the rejected listing page for role = HO2 user
you can see 2 entry in table for HO2 & rejected combination.I want the latest entry from database table. expected output: 27811->Ho2->Rejected
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table_name where id=(SELECT max(id) from table_name where status = 'rejected' and role = 'HO2');
```

But notice, this only works if your id column is auto increment. Otherwise you have to add a TIMESTAMP column and fill the value for each row, then get the latest row by the time.

Comment: its not working because you have passed "status=rejected" in where condition.  (1) its not always possible that latest status in table is rejected, may be its pending also. (2) how can i find all the proposal_id list, which has role = HO2 and latest status = rejected. suppose there are more than 100 record